# how to fix heroku "Application error" where console error "code=H14 desc="No web processes running"

Tags: django, python-3.x, heroku

I'm trying to deploy django project on Heroku. My setting are:

```
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'startshop/static/'),
)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

import dj_database_url
DATABASES = {}
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=600, ssl_require=True)
```

Procfile is - "`web: gunicorn startshop.wsgi --log-file -`"

Runtime is - "python-3.6.6"

WSGI is -

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from whitenoise import WhiteNoise

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "startshop.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
application = WhiteNoise(application)
```

When I typing "heroku ps:scale web=1", I get error "`Couldn't find that process type.`"

Answer (score 0):

Shame on me. The reason was in uppercase letter of procfile file name. I changed

> procfile to **P**rockfile

and my app starts.

Comment: Does that have a k in it? Or is it `Procfile`?

Comment: Not sure. The reason was in first uppercase letter